# How to be sure that the next randomly selected value from an array is not the same as the current one using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am randomly selecting values from an array. I want to be sure that the next selected value is not the same as the current one. How can I implement this rule in Javascript?

```
const pages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * pages.length);
console.log(pages[random]);
```

[image: This is a result of script. I want to avoid the same values next to each other like in the red circle.]

Comment: What is the "current" one? How is this code called/used?

Answer (score 1):

You could filter pages removing current value and only after that select random element.

Answer (score 1):

If the one you pick is the same as the previous one, pick a new one:

```
const pages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * pages.length);
console.log(pages[random]);

let random2;
// Pick a new one:
while (random == ( random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * pages.length)));
```

This assumes every value in the array is different, so it just cares that the two indexes (`random` and `random2`) are different.